In Firefox, Basic polygon only visible after dragging; disappears again when changing map zoom
In Firefox on Ubuntu, using current Google Maps JS API (v3), and I'm trying to add polygon shapes to a map.
(Demo + code further down)
Problem: When adding a shape, it exists but is not visible. I know the shape exists because I see the mouse cursor change when hovering where the shape should be. The shape does become instantly visible as soon as I drag it. It becomes invisible again if I change the map zoom level.
Another interesting thing, when adding multiple shapes (by clicking a "Load" button multiple times in my demo), after the first instance (which is invisible), adding subsequent shapes makes them all visible. However, when changing map zoom, they all return to an invisible state (but still exist, and are draggeable).
Goal: In Firefox on Ubuntu, to have visible shapes on the map at all times, unless I explicitly hide/delete them on my own accord.

A) The shape exists, but is invisible

B) As soon as you drag the invisible shape, it becomes visible

When changing map zoom, the shape returns to (A) invisible.

Demo:
https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/rNgjKwm
Ignore the Google Map warning "This page can't load Google Maps correctly."; everything works enough for this demo.
Button "Load basic polygon" pans to the Bermuda triangle and adds a basic Google Maps polygon.
Button "Load geojson polygon" pans to New Mexico, and adds an arbitrary GeoJSON polygon just above Blue Creek OHV Area.


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), {
  mapId: 'DEMO_MAP_ID',
  center: { lat: 24.3366734, lng: -75.2085759 },
  zoom: 5.25,
  gestureHandling: 'greedy'
})

const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2")

btn1.addEventListener("click", () => loadPolygon_Basic())
btn2.addEventListener("click", () => loadPolygon_GeoJSON())

function loadPolygon_Basic() {
  
  const shape_basic = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
      { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
      { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 }
    ],
    strokeColor: "red",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "lime",
    fillOpacity: 1, 
    visible: true,
    clickable: true,
    draggable: true,
  })
  
  map.setCenter({ lat: 24.3366734, lng: -75.2085759 })
  map.setZoom(5.25)

  shape_basic.setMap(map)
}

function loadPolygon_GeoJSON() {

  const shape_geojson = {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[[[-101.69092517560932,35.760800520027736],[-101.69195514387104,35.73391165725278],[-101.6404567307851,35.73377231306736],[-101.64406161970112,35.764004286494796],[-101.69092517560932,35.760800520027736]]]
    },
    "properties":{}
  }
  
  map.setCenter({ lat: 35.7697449, lng: -101.6806657 })
  map.setZoom(12)
  map.data.addGeoJson(shape_geojson)

  map.data.setStyle({
    fillColor: "green",
    strokeWeight: 1,
    clickable: true,
    draggable: true,
  })
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4em;
  padding: 1px;
}

header div {
  
}

h1 {
font-size: 1em;
}

button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1px;
}

#map1 {
  flex: 1;
}
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<header>
  <h1>Google Maps<br />polygon test</h1>
  
  <div>
    <div>Bermuda triangle</div>
    <button id="btn1">Load basic polygon</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div>New Mexico; arbitrary</div> 
    <button id="btn2">Load geojson polygon</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="map1"></div>




unable to replicate the issue as described. Loading both Polygons is OK and changing zoom level does not cause either Polygon to become invisible

The code snippet works for me (at least as I understand your description).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Really strange; I will try this on other browsers and OS's then. I can replicate on both Codepen and inside the post. I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu.

Update: Apologies, this seems like a Firefox issue. The shapes work fine in Chrome.

The code snippet in the question works for me in firefox (126.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10).

Ok. I'm on Ubuntu using Firefox.

Just tested with Firefox on Ubuntu and it works fine as well.

Dang, idk what's up with my setup then?

I don't know. Try on another computer? Disable extensions (try private browsing)? This has been tested by 3 different people on various setups and it worked just fine.

Set shape style a moment after adding it to the map
Found a trick that seems to work, barring any better solution.
After adding a shape, whether it's basic polygon or GeoJSON, set the shape styles a moment after adding the shape to the map. This seems to force Firefox to properly render the shape.
Basic shape
 //...
 shape_basic.setMap(map)
 //...


setTimeout( () => {
   shape_basic.setOptions({         
    strokeColor: "red",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "lime",
    fillOpacity: 1, 
    visible: true,
    clickable: true,
    draggable: true,
   })
  }, 200)

GeonJSON shape
// ...  
map.data.addGeoJson(shape_geojson)
// ...
  setTimeout( () => {
    map.data.setStyle({
    fillColor: "green",
    strokeWeight: 1,
    clickable: true,
    draggable: true,
    })
  }, 200)


I am on Firefox 126.0.1 on Windows and I can't replicate the issue described. In any case, if you can replicate that bug (nobody seems to be able to) finding a workaround is good but you should file a bug report in their issue tracker.
